# Como treinar uma árvore de decisão no R?

Tags: r, aprendizagem-de-máquina, aprendizado-supervisionado

Digamos que eu tenha os seguintes conjuntos de dados.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- nrow(iris)
indices <- sample(n, n * 0.8)
treino <- iris[indices, ]
teste <- iris[-indices, ]
```

Como eu poderia usar o `R` para treinar uma árvore de decisão capaz de prever a espécie da planta baseado em suas medidas?

Seria bom que a resposta incluísse uma breve explicação sobre o que é uma árvore de decisão e os problemas onde esta solução costuma ser utilizada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem entrar muito fundo na parte teórica, uma árvore de classificação é um modelo matemático que utiliza a estrutura de árvore de decisão para classificar dados. Melhor do que explicar isto em palavras é ver o algoritmo em ação:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
modelo <- rpart(Species ~ ., method="class", data=iris)
prp(modelo, extra=1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que é feita uma pergunta em cada nó da árvore. A resposta da pergunta determina se outra pergunta será feita ou se a árvore chegou ao fim e a classificação foi terminada. Além disso, o erro de classificação é determinado ao final da árvore.

Neste exemplo, as perguntas que o algoritmo fez começam com: `Petal.Length < 2.5`? Se for verdade, então a espécie é classificada como `setosa`. Caso contrário, outra pergunta é realizada: `Petal.Width < 1.8`? Se for verdade, a espécie é classificada como `versicolor`. Caso contrário, é classificada como `virginica`.

Perceba também que, na parte de baixo de cada nó final da árvore, há números que indicam o resultado da classificação. No primeiro nó, todas as 50 `setosa` foram classificadas corretamente. Nos outros dois nós, houve erros de classificação: das 50 `versicolor`, 49 foram classificadas corretamente, mas 5 foram consideradas `virginica`. Dentre as 50 `virginica`, 45 foram classificadas corretamente e 1 foi considerada `versicolor`.

Note que na pergunta original, o autor colocou o seguinte trecho de código:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- nrow(iris)
indices <- sample(n, n * 0.8)
treino <- iris[indices, ]
teste <- iris[-indices, ]
```

Ele fez isso porque um problema que surge no ajuste de modelos de classificação é o [sobreajuste](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreajuste). O sobreajuste ocorre quando o modelo se ajusta muito bem aos dados, se tornando ineficaz para prever observações novas.

O gráfico abaixo ilustra este conceito no contexto de um modelo de classificação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há duas linhas que separam os pontos verdes dos vermelhos. Embora a linha tracejada acerte fielmente todas as classificações que faz, ela acaba não servindo para generalizar o resultado. Caso entrem novas observações no sistema, o modelo gerado pela linha tracejada não terá bom poder preditivo e não servirá para classificar novos dados. Ou seja, ele é muito bom, mas apenas para um conjunto específico de dados. Por isso, o modelo definido pela linha contínua, apesar de errar mais, acaba se tornando mais útil.

Uma forma de evitar este problema é dividindo aleatoriamente o conjunto de dados original em duas partes mutuamente exclusivas. Uma destas partes é chamada de conjunto de treino e, a outra, conjunto de teste. A ideia por trás disso é ajustar o modelo aos dados de treinamento e simular a entrada de novas observações através do conjunto de teste. Assim, é possível verificar quão bem ou quão mal o modelo ajustado está se comportando ao prever observações que não foram utilizadas em seu ajuste.

Esta divisão é possível de ser feita da maneira que foi feita no post original. Particularmente, prefiro utilizar uma função chamada `createDataPartition`, presente no pacote `caret``

```
library(caret)

# definir 75% dos dados para treino, 25% para teste

set.seed(1234)
trainIndex  <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
iris_treino <- iris[ trainIndex, ]
iris_teste  <- iris[-trainIndex, ]
```

Ao fazer `iris_treino <- iris[ trainIndex, ]` eu estou dizendo que o conjunto de dados `iris_treino` vai ter as linhas de `iris` com os números presentes em `trainIndex`. De modo análogo, `iris_teste <- iris[-trainIndex, ]` diz que o conjunto de dados `iris_teste` **não** vai ter as linhas de `iris` com os números presentes em `trainIndex`

Agora tenho dois data frames novos em minha área de trabalho. 75% das observações estão no conjunto de treino e 25% no conjunto de teste. Esta divisão é arbitrária. Normalmente, recomenda-se que o conjunto de treino tenha de 70% a 80% das observações. O restante das observações irá fazer parte do conjunto de teste.

Ocorre que esta divisão dos dados em dois grupos tem uma desvantagem. Isto acaba fazendo com que tenhamos menos dados para ajustar o modelo. E, com menos dados para ajustar o modelo, menos informação temos. Com menos informação, pior ficará nosso modelo. Uma maneira de reduzir este efeito é através da validação cruzada.

A [validação cruzada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o_cruzada) é mais um método utilizado para evitar sobreajuste no modelo. A ideia é ajustar diversas vezes o mesmo modelo em partições (conjuntos mutuamente exclusivos) do conjunto de treinamento original. Neste exemplo eu vou utilizar um método chamado validação cruzada $k$-*fold*.

Esta técnica consiste em cinco passos:

1. Separar o conjunto de treinamento em *k* *folds* (ou partições)
2. Ajustar o modelo em *k-1* *folds*
3. Testar o modelo no *fold* restante
4. Repetir os passos 2 e 3 até que todos os *folds* tenham sido utilizados para teste
5. Calcular a acurácia do modelo

Entretanto, precisamos definir o número de *folds* a serem utilizados na validação cruzada. Em geral, a literatura sugere que de 5 a 10 *folds* sejam usados. O desempenho dos algoritmos não melhora de maneira considerável se aumentarmos muito o número de *folds*.

Dependendo do tamanho do conjunto de dados, é possível que muitos *folds* acabem deixando-nos sem observações para os conjuntos de teste dentro da validação cruzada. Por este motivo, é sempre bom controlar este parâmetro de acordo com o conjunto de dados que estamos estudando.

Com estas técnicas definidas, podemos finalmente passar para o ajuste do modelo.

O `caret` utiliza duas funções para ajustar modelos aos dados, chamadas `train` e `trainControl`. Basicamente, a função `trainControl` estabelece os parâmetros utilizados no ajuste do modelo. Abaixo estou exemplificando como definir que desejamos fazer validação cruzada com 5 *folds*.

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 5)
```

Com os parâmetros da validação cruzada definidos, podemos partir para a o ajuste em si.

```
ajuste_iris <- train(Species ~ ., 
                     data = iris_treino, 
                     method = "rpart", 
                     trControl = fitControl)
```

O resultado do ajuste é o seguinte:

```
CART 

114 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 92, 91, 90, 91, 92 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  cp         Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.0000000  0.9731225  0.9598083
  0.4736842  0.7032938  0.5617284
  0.5000000  0.4429513  0.1866667

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was cp = 0.
```

Não vou entrar no mérito do que significa o hiperparâmetro `cp`. O que importa neste é sultado são `Accuracy` (acurácia) e `Kappa` (tipo a acurácia, exceto que esta medida é normalizada pela chance aleatória de classificação). Vou deixar uma explicação mais detalhada da acurácia e do Kappa em aberto, mas basta saber que tanto a acurácia quanto o Kappa variam entre 0 e 1. Não obstante, quanto maiores estes valores, melhor é o ajuste do modelo.

Portanto, o modelo ajustado conseguiu uma acurácia geral de 95% nos dados de treinamento. Mas isso é só metade do trabalho. Precisamos ver como o modelo se comporta nos dados de teste. Para isso, vamos usar os seguintes comandos:

```
predicao <- predict(ajuste_iris, iris_teste)
confusionMatrix(predicao, iris_teste$Species)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         12          0         0
  versicolor      0         10         2
  virginica       0          2        10

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.8889          
                 95% CI : (0.7394, 0.9689)
    No Information Rate : 0.3333          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 6.677e-12       

                  Kappa : 0.8333          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
Sensitivity                 1.0000            0.8333           0.8333
Specificity                 1.0000            0.9167           0.9167
Pos Pred Value              1.0000            0.8333           0.8333
Neg Pred Value              1.0000            0.9167           0.9167
Prevalence                  0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
Detection Rate              0.3333            0.2778           0.2778
Detection Prevalence        0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
Balanced Accuracy           1.0000            0.8750           0.8750
```

Temos uma acurácia de 88,89% nos dados de teste. Nada mal, considerando que trabalhamos com uma amostra pequena. Além disso, o comando `confusionMatrix` nos dá outras medidas da qualidade do ajuste, como sensitividade (taxa de falsos negativos) e especificidade (taxa de falsos positivos).